# Get duration of remote MP3 file without full download

Tags: node.js

In a node.js script I need to get the duration of a remote MP3 file.

Currently I use [download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/download) and [mp3-duration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mp3-duration) modules to download the file and then compute the duration. It works but the download phase is very long.

I noticed that media players can display the duration almost instantly. Would it be somehow possible to get the duration without downloading the entire file first ?

Comment: You can look at this https://github.com/borewit/music-metadata

Comment: @hurricane Looks interesting, but I can't figure out how to use it with an http url. Could you share, as an answer, a code snippet to extract the appropriate metadata from an http audio stream ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### ID3 Metadatas

mp3 files comes (optionnaly) with metadata called "ID3 tags" :

> ID3 is a de facto standard for metadata in MP3 files

#### ID3v1 enhanced tag

> - The ID3v1 tag occupies 128 bytes, beginning with the string TAG 128 bytes from the end of the file.
> - The Enhanced tag is 227 bytes long, and placed before the ID3v1 tag.

The enhanced tag contains the `start-time` and `end-time` fields as the last 6 + 6 bytes of the tag formated like *mmm:ss*.  So it gives you the duration of the song.

The solution would be to download the 355 last bytes of the file and check if the enhanced tag (`TAG+`) is present, then look for the last 12 bytes of the enhanced tag.

#### ID3v2 TLEN

Nowdays, we're mostly using *ID3v2* which allows us to embed up to 256MB of informations :

*ID3v2* tag is composed of frames. Each frame represents an information. Max frame size is 16MB. Max tag size is 256MB.

The frame you're interested in is the `TLEN` frame, which represent the length of the song.

But there is no guarantee that any mp3 file will have an ID3v2 tag or that the `TLEN` frame will be stored in its ID3v2 tag.

---

**/!\  /!\ /!\** 
If the mp3 file does not contains metadata, the only solution is the one you already came up with : estimating the duration with the *mp3-duration* module.

---

### How to get these metadata without downloading the entire file ?

#### Range requests

If the server accepts [Range Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests), then we just have to tell him the bytes we want !

**ID3v1**

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const NodeID3 = require('node-id3');
const mp3FileURL = "http://musicSite/yourmp3File.mp3";

const mp3FileHEAD = await request.head(mp3FileURL);
const serverAcceptRangeReq = mp3FileHEAD.headers['Accept-Ranges'] && mp3FileHEAD.headers['Accept-Ranges'].toLowerCase() != "none";

// here we assume that the server accepts range requests

const mp3FileSize = mp3FileHEAD.headers['Content-Length'];
const tagBytesHeader = {'Range': `${mp3FileSize - 355}-${mp3FileSize}`};
const tagBytes = await request.get(mp3FileURL, {headers: tagBytesHeader});
```

/!\      *I didn't test the code, it just serves as a demonstration*     /!\

Then parse the response and check if `tagBytes.includes('TAG+')`, and if it does you've got your duration.

**ID3v2**

You can use the same method to check if the ID3v2 tags are at the beginning of the file and then use a module like `node-id3` to parse the tags.

#### GET request to check for ID3v2

According to the documentation,

> The ID3v2 tag header [...] should be the first information in the file, is 10 bytes

So even if the server does not accept Range Requests, you could come up with a solution using a simple GET request and "stopping" it when you receive more than 10 bytes :

```
const request = require('request');
let buff = new Buffer(0);

const r = request
  .get(mp3FileURL)
  .on('data', chunk => {
      buff = Buffer.concat([buff, chunk]);
      if (buff.length > 10) {
          r.abort();
          // deal with your buff
      }
  });
});
```

/!\      *I didn't test the code, it just serves as a demonstration*     /!\

Wrapping it in a function that returns a Promise would be cleaner.